# .htaccess - Rewrite individual URLs to one URL with GET parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I have a list of domains that are specific to individual products, such as
GreatProduct.com
SomeOtherProduct.com
SomeCustomProduct.com
etc.

I want to now redirect these so that they will point to

mydomain.com/products/allproducts.php?prod=ABCD?type=STAND
mydomain.com/products/allproducts.php?prod=ABGH?type=STAND
mydomain.com/products/allproducts.php?prod=ABGH?type=CUSTOM
etc.

(I know there should be "http://www. in front of these, but I'm restricted from posting more than two links)

I am now pointing each domain to a separate root directory, so I intend to place a different .htaccess into each domain's root.

So far, I'm able to use .htaccess to send each domain to mydomain.com/products/allproducts.php, but the parameters are not working properly.

This .htaccess,

```
redirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/products/allproducts.php%3fprod=ABCD%26type=SAME  
redirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/products/allproducts.php%3ftwn=ABCD%26type=SAME
```

results in

mydomain.com/products/allproducts.php%253prod=ABCD%2526type=SAME

I've found lots of examples of turning a paramter-based URL into one without, but nothing like this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@user643373

Does this have to be in an `.htaccess` file?

`mod_rewrite` might provide a solution for this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!allproducts"
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "(.*)"         "http://mydomain.com/products/allproducts.php?prod=%1&type=SAME" [QSA,R=301,L]
```

I don't know what you want to do with the `STAND`, `SAME`, and `CUSTOM` bits..

Comment: This doesn't have to be in an .htaccess file, but I don't know of another way to acomplish the 301 redirect.

Comment: The code, as it is shown, resulted in an "Internal Server Error" on my Apache webserver when I tried it. I don't know if that's due to the code, or to my server configuration.

Comment: I was planning to have this code in the .htaccess file located in the root of each domain. The "STAND", "SAME", and "CUSTOM" flags would be changed in each individual script, where necessary. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user643373 Can you look in your server error log to see what the `500 Internal Server Error` message was about?